# Computing geometric intersection (line-on-polygon overlay) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, intersect

I want to take geometric intersection of line and polygon shapefile. ArcPy has a tool:

```
arcpy.Identity_analysis
```

but it is available with "ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced" and I have "ArcGIS for Desktop Basic".

Is there any alternative tool that I can try?

Comment: It depends a bit on why do you need to get the geometric intersection - could you describe the scenario in the question? Do you need to combine/transfer attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool should provide a suitable alternative.

Both Intersect and Identity perform line-on-polygon overlays but the former keeps only lines sharing a common geography (which includes all geometric intersections) while the latter keeps all lines.

The same tool may be used to perform polygon-on-polygon overlays (with `output_type` of "LINE") to get line features where polygons intersect.